# How to sync records across different name servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

Recently, I have transferred my domain to AWS route53. To prevent domain going missing on the internet I chose to use the old name servers. All the old records are intact and everything went smoothly after the transfer. But when I added a new record in my hosted zone, none of the DNS servers could resolve it.

To solve this problem, I have added AWS provided name servers along with the old name servers in my domain configuration and saw the new record getting resolved in some time. But after doing this my old records were stared getting unresolved by the DNS servers. Please help me in understanding what is going wrong here and how do I solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should try to avoid using multiple sets of Name Servers. Use either your previous ones or the AWS provided records.

**If** you're wanting to use your old name servers then ensure in the Route 53 domain management (not hosted zone) that you set only the nameservers for your previous provider.

**If** you want to use the Route 53 public hosted zone then you will need to update the nameservers to be only those in the public hosted zone. In addition do not modify the `NS` records of the public hosted zone.

Finally ensure that whichever you choose to use, that the complete DNS record set exists. You can't have bits in both. Do not replace `NS` or `SOA` records.

Comment: Okay, what will happen if I change NS records of the public hosted zone(not Route 53 domain management) to old name servers?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, if you do this for a subdomain it would forward the DNS queries to this, but not sure for root domain. Ultimately if you're going to use Route 53 you should leave the NS records as is, otherwise in domain management target the other name servers

Comment: Sure, but I am afraid of services going down after keeping the AWS name servers only, though I have all the records available in my zone file. I am not sure how much time will it take to get new NS records propagated across the DNS servers.

Comment: Ok, but don't try to distribute your DNS across 2 separate configurations :) The configuration will propagate based on the TTLs of the NS records :)